# Compile as C99 file in xcode C++ project

Tags: c++, c, xcode, compilation

I'm writing a C++ project on Xcode7.
my main function is in a cpp file but all of my other files are .c files.
Is there a way to tell the Xcode to compile all of the .c files as c99 and not as cpp files?

Answer (score 2):

`Xcode` will automatically compile each source file based on its file extension.

If you examine the details of the source file in Xcode, you should see the *type* of file Xcode believes it is.

Comment: How do I examine the details of the source file?

Comment: There is properties bar on the right of Xcode when the source file is opened.